# How do I set-up a Printing Macro to run two others macros before printing the pages

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to using Macros but I have run into a situation that has me stumped.  I have a workbook with 3 worksheets ("Inspection Report", "Device List" and "Deficiencies"). I have a Macro on "Device List" and on "Deficiencies" that hides the blank rows.  I want to create a Macro on "Inspection Report" that will operate the Macros to hide the blank rows before printing all 3 pages.

Here is my code.  The first two Sub's are each on there respective worksheets and the last one is in a Module.

```
Sub Hide_Blank_Rows2()
'Hide blank rows on "Device List"
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    [b12:b1108].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Hide_Blank_Rows3()
'Hide blank rows on "Deficiencies"
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    [b49:b156].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Print_All_Pages()
'
' Run Macros to hide blank rows then print all three worksheets
'
Call Hide_Blank_Rows2
Call Hide_Blank_Rows3
'
    Sheets(Array("Inspection Report", "Device List", "Deficiencies")).Select
    Sheets("Inspection Report").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

When I run this I get a Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined.

Comment: I can't replicate.  Is there other code anywhere? What line highlights when you select Debug->Compile from the VBE menu?

Comment: The Sub Print_All_Pages() is highlighted in yellow and Call Hide_Blank_Rows2 is highlighted in blue.

Comment: Totally missed that the code was spread between 3 places.  See the answer below.

Comment: Why put macros on worksheet code modules instead of proper code modules? I really don't see a point to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "Hide" `Subs` are in Worksheets instead of in a Module, they are methods of their respective Worksheets.  You'll need to specify what object to call that method on i.e. (using Sheet2 and Sheet3 as examples):

```
Sheet2.Hide_Blank_Rows2
Sheet3.Hide_Blank_Rows3
```

You can omit the `Call` keyword.

You can also just move the "Hide" Subs to a module.  If you *leave* them on the Worksheets, replacing the references to `ActiveSheet` with `Me` will solve the bug that you haven't got to yet (you never change the ActiveSheet before calling the 2 `Subs` or between them):

```
Sub Hide_Blank_Rows2()
'Hide blank rows on "Device List"
  Me.Unprotect Password:=""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    [b12:b1108].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
  Me.Protect Password:=""

End Sub
```

If you *do* move them to a module, you'll want to specifically address a Worksheet to operate on in order to solve the bug that you haven't got to yet.  I'd personally just combine them into one `Sub` something like this...

```
Sub Hide_Blank_Rows(sh As Worksheet, targetRange As String)
    sh.Unprotect Password:=""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    sh.Range(targetRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
    sh.Protect Password:=""
End Sub
```

...and put it in the same place as `Sub Print_All_Pages()`.

You would call it like this:

```
Hide_Blank_Rows Sheets("Device List"), "B12:B1108"
Hide_Blank_Rows Sheets("Deficiencies"), "B49:B156"
```

Comment: Thanks Comintern.  I went with changing the 'ActiveSheet' to 'Me'.  It now works the way I need it to.